# Conditional drop down is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a filtering drop downs on hover, where by selecting the country name on hover from the first drop down the respective destinations will appear in the second drop down on hover. But It is not working in internet explorer & also in edge why?

```
function changeddl(obj) {

 var text = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
 var ddl2 = document.querySelectorAll('#iOperation option');
for (var i = 1; i < ddl2.length; i++) {
var option = ddl2[i];
option.style.display = 'none';
if (text == 'Pick a Country') {
  if (['Pick a Destination'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
    option.style.display = 'none'

}

if (text == 'India') {
  if (['Bangalore', 'Delhi', 'Pune','Gujarat','Rajastan','Goa','Haryana','Kerela','Hampi'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
    option.style.display = 'block'

}
if (text == 'Sri Lanka') {
  if (['colombio','fetero','Kandy','Galle','Nuwara','Negombo'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
    option.style.display = 'block'
}

if (text == 'Swedan') {
  if (['Swedan'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
    option.style.display = 'block'
}
}
}

  function DropList() {
   var n = document.getElementById("iFunction").options.length;
  document.getElementById("iFunction").size = n;
  }

  function handleSelect(elm){
 window.location = elm.value;
 }



 var countryArrays = [ ['Bangalore', 'Delhi','Pune','Gujarat','Rajastan','Goa','Haryana','Kerela','Hampi'],
    ['colombio','fetero','Kandy','Galle','Nuwara','Negombo'],['Swedan'] ];

 function DropNew() {

 var index = document.getElementById("iFunction").selectedIndex - 1;

if (index >= 0){
document.getElementById("iOperation").size = countryArrays[index].length + 1;
} else {
jQuery("#popup").show();
 }
  }

 function hidePopup() {
jQuery("#popup").hide();
 }
    function handleSelect(elm){
 window.location = elm.value;
```

}

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Welcome! Please share some code and log errors.